# Xcode 15 Organizer Crashes

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode-organizer

I have recently updated Xcode and when attempting to look at the feedback from testers in the organizers, Xcode consistently crashes. In the organizer window, when I clicked Feedback, Xcode completely crashes. It didn't crash when the builds were displayed. Now whenever I attempt to open organizer, even after creating a build, the Organizer window automatically crashes Xcode.

I even attempted to download Xcode 15.1 beta and have the same issue, and Xcode 14 doesn't run on my Mac since updating MacOS.

Has anyone experience this? If so how did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some steps you can take to try to resolve this issue:

1.Delete Derived Data:

Close Xcode.
Delete the Derived Data folder. You can find it at ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData.
Restart Xcode.

2.Reset Xcode:

Open Terminal and run the command: defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode.
This will reset some of Xcode's settings to their defaults. Please note that any custom settings or preferences will be lost.

3.Clear Cache:

Sometimes, Xcode's caches can cause issues. You can try to clear them by running the following command in Terminal: rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode.

4.Reinstall Xcode:

Uninstall Xcode completely by dragging it to the trash, then reinstall it from the Mac App Store.

5.Check System Logs:

Open Console.app and look for any crash logs related to Xcode. This might give you more detailed information about what's causing the crash.

6.Contact Apple Developer Support:

If none of the above steps work, you might want to reach out to Apple Developer Support for assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Please agree updated agreement at https://developer.apple.com/account and try to upload it again.